# Interpreting Bootstrap results in R

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap

I have two different sized datasets, so am attempting to use the bootstrap function. I have completed the code below, but am not sure how to interpret the results. Any help would be great

```
# bootstrapping with 1000 replications
results <- boot(data=Timedata, statistic=rsq,
                R=1000, formula=Max_Height~Age*Time_period)

# view results
`results
plot(results)`
```

ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP

Call:

```
boot(data = Timedata, statistic = rsq, R = 1000, formula = Max_Height ~ 
    Age * Time_period)
```

Bootstrap Statistics :

```
     original        bias    std. error
t1* 0.7439122 -0.0003189452  0.06257858
```

## get 95% confidence interval

`boot.ci(results, type="bca")
 ?boot.ci`

BOOTSTRAP CONFIDENCE INTERVAL CALCULATIONS
Based on 1000 bootstrap replicates

CALL : 
boot.ci(boot.out = results, type = "bca")

Intervals : 
Level       BCa
95%   ( 0.5794,  0.8343 )
Calculations and Intervals on Original Scale

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to interpret your example without any context or reproducibility so I'll describe in detail how to interpret the results using a simplified `boot` example.

Using the standard `mtcars` data, suppose we want to calculate the **Bootstrap** mean of the `mpg` column. That is, we have the sample mean, but we want to get the **Bootstrap** mean of `mpg`.

```r
    library(boot)

    set.seed(231241)
    mean_df <- function(dataset, i) mean(dataset[i, "mpg"])
    res <- boot(mtcars, mean_df, 999)
    res
    #> 
    #> ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP
    #> 
    #> 
    #> Call:
    #> boot(data = mtcars, statistic = mean_df, R = 999)
    #> 
    #> 
    #> Bootstrap Statistics :
    #>     original      bias    std. error
    #> t1* 20.09062 -0.01391391    1.060334
```

The output of `boot` means that the original mean `20.09062` is the mean of `mpg` on without bootstrap. We can check that with:

```r
    mean(mtcars$mpg)
    #> [1] 20.09062
```

The bias column showing `-0.01391391` shows the difference between the bootstrapped mean and the sample mean from above. We can check that with:

```r
    # Bias is the difference between the sample mean
    # and the sample Bootstrap
    mean(res$t) - res$t0
    #> [1] -0.01391391
```

Since the bootstrap is just `N` number of resamples from the original data, it should contain a resample of means. The standard error presented here is just the standard deviations of all of your bootstrapped means. We can check that with:

```r
    # And the standard error is the standard deviation
    # of the bootstrapped sample
    sd(res$t)
    #> [1] 1.060334
```

You can probably extrapolate this to your example. For example, your original result of `0.7439122` is probably the R square of your model, where the bias of `-0.0003189452` is the average difference between your bootstrapped R squares. Additionally, the standard error is just the standard deviation of all your bootstrapped R squared.

Finally, the `boot.ci` just calculates the confidence interval of your bootstrapped estimate described above with the standard error of all your bootstraps.

```r
    res_ci <- boot.ci(res)
    #> Warning in boot.ci(res): bootstrap variances needed for studentized intervals

    res_ci
    #> BOOTSTRAP CONFIDENCE INTERVAL CALCULATIONS
    #> Based on 999 bootstrap replicates
    #> 
    #> CALL : 
    #> boot.ci(boot.out = res)
    #> 
    #> Intervals : 
    #> Level      Normal              Basic         
    #> 95%   (18.03, 22.18 )   (17.95, 22.16 )  
    #> 
    #> Level     Percentile            BCa          
    #> 95%   (18.02, 22.23 )   (18.08, 22.31 )  
    #> Calculations and Intervals on Original Scale
```